# why is my Spring application getting wrong data from a MariaDB database?

Tags: java, spring, mariadb

I'm writing a Spring application that gets data from a MariaDB server and does stuff that I haven't implemented yet because the application is getting wrong data from the server:

[image]

As you can see on the right there is the data I want to show up in my application and Spring keeps showing up in the browser the right number of occurrences but for every `market_id` just the first `stock_id` (I tried changing data, creating a new table and changing browser, the result is always the same).

Here's the code:

the market_stocks's spring entity

```
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class MarketsStocks {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)

    private Integer marketId;

    private Integer stockId;

    public Integer getMarketId() {
        return marketId;
    }

    public void setMarketId(Integer marketId) {
        this.marketId = marketId;
    }

    public Integer getStockId() {
        return stockId;
    }

    public void setStockId(Integer stockId) {
        this.stockId = stockId;
    }
}
```

and its repository

```
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface MarketsStocksRepository extends CrudRepository<MarketsStocks, Integer> {
}
```

and here the snippet I use in the controller

```
@GetMapping(path = "/get-markets-stocks")
    public @ResponseBody Iterable<MarketsStocks> getMarketsStocks(){
        return marketsStocksRepository.findAll();
    }
```

Comment: You should have a `Market` class which has alink to `Stocks`. The table you now have mapped is a join table for a many-to-many relation. You defined id as `marketId` and an id (or primary key) has to be unique, hence there can only be one `MarketsStocks`. So it isn't problem of Spring but the fact that your JPA mapping are wrong. It does exactly what you designed it to do, which might not be want you wanted.

Comment: Have you checked the SQL query that is actually executed?